# Catching selected portion of xml files

Tags: python, xml-parsing

My xml file is like this

```
<S_Row>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody></S_CellBody></S_Cell>
</S_Row>
```

I am handling it in python like this:

```
for S_Cell in S_Row.findall('S_Cell'):
        for S_CellBody in S_Cell.getchildren():
              S_CellBody.text="ABC"
```

This gives me output like this in xml file:

```
  <S_Row>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody>ABC</S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody>ABC</S_CellBody></S_Cell>
     <S_Cell><S_CellBody>ABC</S_CellBody></S_Cell>
   </S_Row>
```

What if I want to insert ABC in 1st row or 2nd row or 3rd row?
How can I keep the track of the rows I am getting, as S_Cell.getchildren() is giving me all rows.

I want to keep the track of record through which I can insert text in my selected row(either 1st,2nd or 3rd row.)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
for i, S_Cell in enumerate(S_Row.findall('S_Cell')):
    for S_CellBody in S_Cell.getchildren():
          S_CellBody.text = str(i)
```

You can put some `if`s statements in the loop, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable:

```
i = 0
for S_CellBody in S_Cell.getchildren():
    i += 1
    if i == 2:
        S_CellBody.text = "ABC"
```

Comment: Doesn't help, its not increasing the value of i within the loops